# Generic method in Java with arbitary return type and Jackson serializer

Tags: java, json, generics, jackson

I'm using Jackson + ES to de-serialize JSON objects to java POJO. I'm using a simple method that iterates over SearchResponse provided by ElasticSearch:

```
private List<MyPOJO> toObjects(SearchResponse searchResponse)
{
    List<MyPOJO> _objects = new ArrayList<>();

    for(SearchHit searchHit: searchResponse.getHits().hits()){
        try {
            MyPOJO _object = json.readValue(searchHit.source(), MyPOJO.class);
            _objects.add(_object);
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return _objects;
} // ND: json is a Jackson ObjectMapper instance.
```

Considering that I reuse a lot this code for every POJO, I'm trying to convert it in order to accept arbitrary types instead of fixed MyPOJO type.
Is it possibile in Java? I searched for Class< ? > generic type and T, but the compiler always give me errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass `Class<T>` argument to `toObjects` function

```
private <T> List<T> toObjects(SearchResponse searchResponse, Class<T> clazz)
```

and add `clazz` to `readValue` call

```
T _object = json.readValue(searchHit.source(), clazz);
```

It is a straightforward way.

If you *really* have to build reader on generics (`class ResponseReader<T>`) it is possible via reflection, but you should avoid this way as long as possible because it leads to very complicated and fragile code (and bad performance).

Comment: Perfect! It's exactly what I needed.
By the way, what are you referring to for "build reader on generics"?

Comment: "build reader on generics" refer to you point about "Class<?> generic type". If you have a class `ResponseReader<T>` it is possible to obtain current value of `T` inside member of this class using `this.getClass()` and some weird magic like https://github.com/jhalterman/typetools/blob/master/src/main/java/net/jodah/typetools/TypeResolver.java#L146